# Передавать в программу время компиляции

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Хочу отслеживать версии программы, по времени компиляции.
Как проще всего такое можно реалиховать для VS2017 C#.
Единственное что приходит в голову, создать программу (time_now.exe), которая будет менять содержимое кода, а именно `public static readonly  DateTime VersionSoft = new DateTime(_year, _month, _day, _hour, _minute, _second, _millisecond);` . Где вместо _year,... будет результат работы сторонней программки.
А компилятору сказать что бы прежде чем компилировал, запусти пожалуйста time_now.exe.
Если ли выход лучше, и как реализовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В простейшем случае вам достаточно указать в файле `AssemblyInfo.cs` вот такой код:

```
[assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

Компилятор подставит на место звездочки вычисленные из даты и времени значения.

В более сложном случае вы можете и правда написать свою программу которая будет генерировать файл с кодом. Но лучше все же воспользоваться возможностями системы сборки.

1. Через контекстное меню выгружаете проект
2. Там же открываете его как XML-файл
3. Дописываете в него перед закрывающим тэгом:

```
<Target Name="MakeVersionInfo" BeforeTargets="Compile">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <_VersionInfo>
using System;
namespace Foo.Properties
{ 
    class VersionInfo
    { 
         public static readonly DateTime BuildDate = new DateTime($([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Ticks));
    }
}
        </_VersionInfo>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <WriteLinesToFile File="Properties\VerisonInfo.cs" Lines="$(_VersionInfo.Replace(';', '%3b'))" Overwrite="true" />
</Target>
```

Или вот так если не нравится костыль через Replace:

```
<Target Name="MakeVersionInfo" BeforeTargets="Compile">
    <ItemGroup>
        <_VersionInfo Include="Properties\VerisonInfo.cs">
            <Data>
using System;
namespace Foo.Properties
{ 
    class VersionInfo
    { 
         public static readonly DateTime BuildDate = new DateTime($([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Ticks));
    }
}
            </Data>
        </_VersionInfo>
    </ItemGroup>

    <WriteLinesToFile File="@(_VersionInfo)" Lines="@(_VersionInfo->'%(Data)')" Overwrite="true" />
</Target>
```

Осталось файл `Properties\VerisonInfo.cs` добавить к проекту (и исключить из системы контроля версий если вы ее используете).

Comment: а можно поподробнее, что такое "контекстное меню выгружаете проект"?

Comment: @KtoTo извиняюсь, там одна звездочка должна быть

Comment: @KtoTo а что непонятного во фразе "Через контекстное меню выгружаете проект"?

Comment: @PavelMayorov - слова  "контекстное", "меню", "выгружаете" и "проект". Слово "через" - понятно.

Comment: @Igor ну извините, понятие "контекстное меню" относится к базовым понятиям при работе с GUI

Comment: Попробуйте почитать "Windows для чайников", там должны рассказывать что это такое.

Comment: Граждане, мне что, надо было "смайлик" ставить? *- маленькая иллюстрация к дискуссии об уместности иронии в комментариях* **:)**

Comment: я разобрался и с контекстным меню и выгрузкой. После вставки кода, появилась ошибка: `нераспознанный атрибут "BeforeTarget" в элементе <Target>`

Comment: @KtoTo извиняюсь, там множественное число должно быть

Comment: открылся. А как теперь обратиться к версии?

Comment: @PavelMayorov что я как я должен запросить версию?

Comment: @KtoTo `Properties.VersionInfo.BuildDate`. А вы как пытаетесь?

Comment: @KtoTo вы же не забыли сгенерированный после первой компиляции файл в проект добавить?

Comment: @PavelMayorov сгенерированный файл создается без ;. как исправить?

Comment: @KtoTo исправил. Пробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

> создать программу (time_now.exe), которая будет менять содержимое кода

Это хороший, вполне рабочий способ. Вот только он, по сути, уже встроен в Visual Studio.

И этот способ называется T4 - Text Template Transformation Toolkit.

Добавляем в проект Text Template, он имеет расширение `.tt`. В нём пишем:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

using System;

public class VersionHelper
{
    public static readonly DateTime VersionSoft = new DateTime(<#= DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks #>);
}
```

Компилируем проект или просто сохраняем этот файл. Появится файл `.cs` с таким же названием. В нём будет вставлено время на момент сохранения файла.

Чтобы файл `.cs` генерировался (обновлялся) при каждом билде, можно воспользоваться одним из способов, описанных в [этой](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646580/5045688) теме.

Теперь можно использовать сгенерированный код:

```
Console.WriteLine(VersionHelper.VersionSoft);
```

---

Отмечу, что часто при первом использовании T4 возникают проблемы с распознаванием сгенерированного кода. Достаточно закрыть проект (File > Close) и открыть его снова.

Comment: Вы забыли рассказать как настроить T4 чтобы он работал при сборке - потому что по умолчанию он работает только когда вы сохраняете файл с шаблоном. Кстати, встроен этот способ не в C#, а в студию.

Comment: @PavelMayorov - большое спасибо за комментарий. Не знал, что генерация происходит при сохранении.