# Генерирование версии программы

Tags: c#, .net

Можно ли сделать так, что бы в Caption формы при каждой компиляции программы выполнялся автоматический инкремент версии?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Почему версия должна инкрементироваться именно в caption?

Comment: Можно использовать T4. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/776419/184217

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Атрибут `[assembly: AssemblyVersion(...)]` может использоваться для автоматической нумерации, если вы укажете его в формате

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

или

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.*")]
```

При этом обозначенные звёздочками части версии будут подсчитаны автоматически. Например, третья часть версии (build) будет подсчитана как количество полных дней с 1.1.2000, то есть, по формуле

```
(DateTime.Now - new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)).Days
```

Это даст увеличение build number каждый день.

Четвёртая часть (revision) будет подсчитана как половина количества секунд от начала текущих суток, не беря в расчёт летнее время. Это даст увеличение номера revision каждые две секунды.

Документация: [AssemblyVersionAttribute @ docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute?view=netframework-4.7.1).

---

Для того, чтобы получить номер версии, можно использовать

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

(ну и `ToString()`, если нужно для вывода).

---

Компоненты Windows, судя по всему, используют похожую схему версионирования, но немного другую. Например, мой экземпляр `cmd.exe` имеет версию 10.0.16299.15. [Это отдалённо похоже на отсчёт с Unix epoch, но интернет не подтверждает это.]

---

Ещё по теме: [Передавать в программу время компиляции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/776137/10105).

Comment: Там можно версию ещё выбирать, мажорную, минорную, и тд. [Пример](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/a0864480764b931303fa4e49e603a3bd4880b2cd/src/Arma3BE.Client/Shell.xaml.cs#L17), сам [тип](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @tym32167, вместо `{version.Major}.{version.Minor}.{version.Build}` можно написать просто `{version.ToString(3)}`

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо, но мне в моей версии более понятно, что происходит

Comment: @VladD, 10.0.16299.15 выпущена 20.03.2017. Судя по всему там другой принцип, потому что до этого была сборка 15063.0 от 20.03.2017. Версии компонентов соответствуют версии ОС

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Возможно, это дата билда первой публичной беты или какого-нибудь manufacturer preview?

Comment: @VladD, вообще не похоже это на дату, слишком большая разница: 10240-10586-14393-15063-16299  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10#Поддержка

Comment: @АндрейNOP: Хм, и правда. Убрал неверные утверждения из ответа.